# interactive report filter and plsql function

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I use plsql function with interactive report row filter? I have function in the workspace with application, but seems that apex allow to use only functions from the list Functions/Operators.

Any workaround for this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, I have added additional column that holds return value of that plsql function. Pretty easy.